# What does this instanceof error message mean?

Tags: javascript, instanceof

I was playing around with `instanceof` in Chrome but I got an error message. I *think* I know why (you have to supply a function after the `instanceof` keyword that is the constructor the object was created with), but the error message seems to be stating something else:

```
[1,2,3] instanceof Array
// true

[1,2,3] instanceof []
// TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got 1,2,3
```

Does this mean that I should replace `[1,2,3]` with a function? I would think that `[1,2,3]` is correct and that `[]` is the problem and should be replaced with a function, but it looks like the error message is saying the opposite.

Could someone please explain how I'm interpreting the error message incorrectly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Objects are instances of a constructor function, so the test is to see if the left hand is an *instance of* the right, so the right must be a function (and it must be the constructor that constructed the object to return `true`).

```
[1,2,3] instanceof [].constructor;  // true
```

---

So to answer the question more directly, your initial understanding is correct, and the error message seems misleading (to me anyway).

From the spec: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.8.6

> **1.8.6   The instanceof operator**
>
> The production RelationalExpression: RelationalExpression instanceof ShiftExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> - Let lref be the result of evaluating RelationalExpression.
> - Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> - Let rref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> - Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> - If Type(rval) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> - **If rval does not have a [[HasInstance]] internal method, throw a TypeError exception.**
> - Return the result of calling the [[HasInstance]] internal method of rval with argument lval.

and http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.3.5

**15.3.5   Properties of Function Instances**

> In addition to the required internal properties, every function instance has a [[Call]] internal property and in most cases use a different version of the [[Get]] internal property. **Depending on how they are created (see 8.6.2 ,13.2, 15, and 15.3.4.5), function instances may have a [[HasInstance]] internal property**, a [[Scope]] internal property, a [[Construct]] internal property, a [[FormalParameters]] internal property, a [[Code]] internal property, a [[TargetFunction]] internal property, a [[BoundThis]] internal property, and a [[BoundArgs]] internal property.

So it requires a `TypeError` if the right hand does not have an internal `[[HasInstance]]` property, but doesn't specify the wording.

Firefox 4 gives me a much more sensible error message:

```
[1,2,3] instanceof [];

// TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand []
```

Comment: Ah OK, so the error message stating that it expects a function instead of what's placed on the left is not really worded well, is that correct?

Comment: @pimvdb: Yeah, I don't understand why it's worded that way.

Comment: "it must be the constructor that constructed the object to return true" Not entirely true. The instanceof operator checks to see if the left operand inherits from the prototype property of the right operand. So if an object is built by a constructor, and that constructor happens to reference the same object in its prototype property as another constructor, instanceof will return true if that object is tested against both: `var obj={x:1};var class_one=function(){};class_one.prototype=obj;var class_two=function(){};class_two.prototype = obj;var inst = new class_one;inst instanceof class_two;`