# Javascript, behavior of instanceof function

Tags: javascript, node.js, instanceof

I'm creating a Node.js application. I have a project with this structure:

```
[Project Folder]
  |
  |---[plc]
  |     |--- plc.js
  |     |--- scheduler.js
  |
  |---[source]
  |     |--- source.js
  |
  |---[test]
        |--- test.js
```

The files *plc.js*, *scheduler.js* and *source.js* are "objects", they require other objects and, at the end of file, have an "export" of the object.
In particular the file *plc.js* has an weird behavior. First the code:

```
var mod_pollist     = require('./polling_list.js');     // Polling list.
var mod_operation   = require('./operation.js');        // Single operation.
var mod_scheduler   = require('./scheduler.js');        // Scheduler object.
var mod_events      = require('events');            // Event emitter
var mod_util        = require('../util.js');        // Util functions

function plc(comm_driver){
    var self = this;
    // Other variables are set here
}

// Other functions written as plc.prototype.something = function(parameters){...}

module.exports = plc;
```

Now the weird behavior: all the other files have at the top of the file the code for importing the *plc.js* ( `var mod_plc = require('../plc/plc.js');` or `var mod_plc = require('./plc.js');` for the scheduler) but only in *test.js* it works correctly, infact if I write

```
if(PLC instanceof mod_plc)
    console.log('yes');
```

in the file *test.js* I can find a 'yes' on the console, if I write the same code in the other files I obtain an error:

```
if(PLC instanceof mod_plc)
                  ^
TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<Object>
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Massimo\workspace\Scada\plc\scheduler.js:16:
19)
```

A "temporary solution" could be

```
if(PLC instanceof mod_plc.constructor)
    console.log('yes');
```

but I don't think is the real solution because with all other objects (I've more than 20 files written like *plc.js*) this problem doesn't exist.

Any suggestion? Do you need more informations?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this instanceof error message mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021245/what-does-this-instanceof-error-message-mean)

Comment: What does the export declaration from plc.js look like?

Comment: Given that the `TypeError` tells you `mod_plc` is an `Object` (and not a constructor function) and that it works with `mod_plc.constructor`, I'd say the module (such as `scheduler.js`) is exporting a new instance of `plc` and not the function itself.

Comment: @jbabey it isn't a duplicate because the 'instanceof' works well with ALL other objects in the project. That solution works but I think it can't be the REAL solution of my problem.

Comment: @pgreen2 I don't understand the question

Comment: @c24w Scheduler.js has only a `module.exports = scheduler;` at the end and a `var mod_plc = require('./plc.js');`.
In the other parts of code the plc is used only as reference

Comment: @MaxMarkson: Ignore my mention of `scheduler.js`, I confused myself a bit.  Still, it seems like your `PLC` variable has somewhere been assigned an instance of `mod_plc`.

Comment: @c24w Well, your mistake is the correct intuition to get the answer! I made some tests and the error lies in the use of the objects: Plc use a Scheduler object, Scheduler object use a Plc object and this generate the weird behavior.

Now, only Scheduler use a Plc object and even in all other files the instanceof work!
Thanks :)

Comment: Or better: Write your idea in a reply, so I can choose it as best answer and in a comment I explain the solution...in that way you can earn the reputation you deserve :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise my comments from above:

Given that:

- the `TypeError` tells you `mod_plc` is an `Object` (not a constructor function); and
- using `mod_plc.constructor` gives you the expected behaviour;

it looks like your `PLC` variable has somewhere been assigned an instance of `mod_plc` (hence is no longer a reference to the expected constructor function).